# калькулятор кредита

Tags: javascript

Когда считаешь второй раз результат не обновляет, а просто идет внизу с первой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/Fetko_d/pen/wQeJGW вот код

Comment: Вопрос должен включать в себя [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

В коде таблица не чистится перед добавление результатов. 
В начале функции `calc_btn.onclick` нужно добавить

```
const tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
tbody.innerHTML  = '';
```

Comment: добавил, все работает. но пропал верхняя часть калькулятора

Comment: @Gev чтобы получить нормальный ответ (и ничего не пропадало) нужно задать нормально вопрос (а именно добавить `html` код в вопрос как минимум) очевидно у вас все находится в `tbody` вот и исчезает

Comment: @Gev хотя если попробовать добавить код в вашей ссылке, то все норм работает